# OpenCV: finding the coordinates of intersections of lines in the photo

Tags: c++, opencv, vision

I'm just starting to learn OpenCV programming. I would like to know if it is possible to get coordinates of intersections of lines (veins) from this photo.

http://mormometricanalysis.wu.cz/photo.JPG

In the photo there are marked needed points with the red colour. I want to calculate angles between lines, length of lines and area - examples below.

http://mormometricanalysis.wu.cz/

I have done some research about this problematic. But mostly the examples were about finding lines in a binary image - I don't know if I can make quality binary image from this photo in OpenCV. Computation of coordinates of points should be as precise as it can be.

Is there any function in OpenCV to do that? Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have to pass on the finding intersections part, but in order to get a binary image, your first step should be the following:

Treshold the image. This should work fine, if the contrast is always as high as in the example. Alternatively try edge detection.

As for finding lines that fit the veins I have a vague idea. Let me try to put it in words:

- Try to find an area of high density in the binary image and determine the center [x1,y1].
- Define a line with one fixed point in the center of this area f(x-x1) = m*x + y1
- Rotate the line by varying m and optimize for a maximum correlation between the binary image of the line and the binary image of the veins
- When you found the maximum of the correlation, cut the section of the line, that actually overlaps with a vein
- Repeat with the next center of high density

This might/should give you a bunch of parametrically defined lines where you can easily determine the intersections and angles.